# Htaccess Rewrite Rule for showing title & category id in url

Tags: php, .htaccess

I want to display my title in the url as well as category & subcategory like this.

http://www.phpshiksha.com/php-tutorials-set-time-zone/22-14

I want that this will call a page name default.php or whatever and I will be able to get the category id  22 and subcategory id 14 on the page.May i know what will be the .htaccess rewtite rule for this.

I will appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should get you started

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([0-9A-Za-z\-]+)/([0-9]+)-([0-9]+) main.php?title=$1&cat=$2&subcat=$3
```

It should result in a $_GET array like the following

```
array(3) {
  ["title"]=>
  string(27) "php-tutorials-set-time-zone"
  ["cat"]=>
  string(2) "22"
  ["subcat"]=>
  string(2) "14"
}
```

Comment: Can you please also help me to write the rule for http://www.phpshiksha.com/index.php to http://www.phpshiksha.com/home  I will be thankful of you

Answer (score 0):

rule for phpshiksha.com/index.php to phpshiksha.com/home

```
RewriteRule index.php home
```

Comment: no,its did not work and showing error Not Found

The requested URL /home was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.can you help me to sort it out

Comment: What o you wnat to do? so that the user types http://website.com/home and sees the index.php-page in the root or user comes to index.php and have to be redirected to /home folder?

Comment: I want that any one will www.mysite.com/home then it will call the index.php which is in the www.mysite.com